# How to Update image through stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table where there is a column of type image. I am getting the schema name (here it is `cid`) dynamically. I am trying to update the image column as below

```
SET @SQL1 = 'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@cid) + '.[QueenBase].[queen_user] ' + 
            'SET [resizedimage] = ' + CAST(@resizedimage AS image) + 
            ' WHERE userid = ''' + CAST(@userid AS VARCHAR(30)) + '''';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL1;
```

I am getting an error:

> The data types nvarchar and image are incompatible in the add operator.

Where did I make a mistake? What is the right way to update the image?

Comment: please do not spam the tag. Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: From the usage of `QUOTENAME` and `sys.sp_executesql` I'd suggest that this is T-SQL, *not* MySQL.

Comment: @Squirrel Ya it is SQL Server

Comment: "there is a column of type image" - image type is deprecated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: 2 questions: 1. *Why* are you using the `image` data type? It was deprecated in 2005 and should **not** be used. 2. Why are you **injecting** your parameters? *Parametrise* them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems here.

1. You're using the `image` data type. `image` was deprecated in **2005** (that's *16* years ago) and should not be use. Use `varbinary(MAX)`.
2. You are injecting your parameters. **Parametrise** your parameters (seems silly when I say it, right?), don't inject them. This point is the reason for your error.

If we fix both of these problems, we end up with the following:

```sql
SET @SQL1 = N'UPDATE '+QUOTENAME(@cid) + N'.[QueenBase].[queen_user] SET [resizedimage]=@resizedimage WHERE userid=@userid;';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL1, N'@resizedimage varbinary(MAX), @userid int', @resizedimage, @userid; --Data type of @userid guessed. Correct as needed
```

Comment: I have updated my Stored procedure. Now I am not getting the error, but dont know why the columns are not getting updated

Comment: *"Now I am not getting the error"*... That tells me nothing about what the error is. *I*, nor anyone else here, can run your SQL so we have no idea what the problem is.